# How to extract text and remove HTML tags in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, text-classification

I have a free text field column in python dataframe with html tags.

```
ID Free text field
    1   <p><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(37, 36, 35); font-family: 
        Arial; font-size: 10.5pt;">TExt1:</span></p><p><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 
        255); color: rgb(37, 36, 35); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10.5pt;">Score: 5</span></p><p> 
        <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(37, 36, 35); font-family: Arial; 
         font-size: 10.5pt;">B - </span><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: 
         rgb(36, 36, 36); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10.5pt;">TExt2</span></p><p><span 
         style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(37, 36, 35); font-family: Arial; 
         font-size: 10.5pt;">Text6</span></p><p><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
         color: rgb(37, 36, 35); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10.5pt;">Text3</span></p><p><span 
         style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(37, 36, 35); font-family: Arial; 
         font-size: 10.5pt;">Text4</span></p>
    2   <p>Text10</p>
    3   <p>Sky is blue</p>
    4   <p>Text3</p><p><br></p><p>Text19</p>
    5   <p> Complaint1</p><p><br></p><p>Text1</p><p>hospo 2</p><p>Tes45</p><p><br></p><p>test</p>
    6   <p>Test44</p>
    7   <p>Test54</p>
```

Tried using this;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df['free text'].apply(
    lambda x: list(BeautifulSoup(x, "html.parser").stripped_strings)
)
```

but getting this error,

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want the actual text in another column? What do you mean by "remove HTML tags into another column in pandas"?

Comment: yes, in another column

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to remove all missing data using 'df.dropna()' before applying the lambda function, otherwise you will get 'TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()' error if your data frame has missing data.